# How is the proper way to call focus function on element

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning javascript And I want to call focus() function on input field but am getting no luck how am I doing wrong here down below is how I have tried

```
function findItemById(id){
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

function gofocus(){
    switch(findItemById(id)){
        case findItemById("txtBCode"): findItemById("txtBCode").focus();break;
        case findItemById("txtBName"): findItemById("txtBName").focus();break;
        case findItemById("txtSBicCode"): findItemById("txtSBicCode").focus();break;
        case findItemById("chkLBank"): findItemById("chkLBank").focus();break;
        case findItemById("txtBType"): findItemById("txtBType").focus();break;
        case findItemById("txtHOCountry"): findItemById("txtHOCountry").focus();break;
        case findItemById("txtMICRCode"): findItemById("txtMICRCode").focus();break;
        case findItemById("chkAFlag"): findItemById("chkAFlag").focus();break;
        case finditemById("chkCBank"): findItemById("chkCBank").focus();break;
        case findItemById("txtRIGSid"): findItemById("txtRIGSid").focus();break;
    }
}
```

and on input field there is attribute called onfocus="my function go focus"

```
<input type="text" id="field" placeholder="Type here" onfocus="gofocus">
```

pleas could someone advise how to proper do this. I apologize for my English I am using translator to try to ask.

Comment: Please don't tag-spam. This has nothing to do with [tag:node.js] or [tag:jsp].

Comment: @I am using <script></script> tag inside of jsp file

Comment: That's irrelevant to the question above.

Comment: **The problem is basically a typo.** What you have is odd, but would work if the `onfocus` attribute were correct. If you have a global function called `gofocus`, the `onfocus` should be `onfocus="gofocus()"`. That said, I strongly recommend using proper event handling, not `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers.

Comment: For what it's worth, that `switch` seems **very** odd. I don't see why you need a switch at all. Why not just `if (["txtBCode", "txtBName", /*...*/].includes(id)) { findItemById(id).focus(); }`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you for sharing the wisdom with me be blessed

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73916814/add-multiple-element-to-single-onkeypress-onkeyup-and-onkeydown` I would appreciate your insight on this issue as well, sir.